# how to set textbox only access numbers,decimals

Tags: vb.net, keypress

i am using key press event. its working.. but i need to display decimal values. it only access with out ".(dot)"

```
If txtunit. Focused = True Then    
   If Not Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) And Not e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Back) Then 
      e.Handled = True
   End If
End If
```

Comment: Also remember that users can paste values into your text box.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include `Chr(46)` is which is for the Period.

```
   If (Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) And Not e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Back) And Not e.KeyChar = Chr(46)) Then
       e.Handled = True
   End If
```

If you want to disable pasting in your textbox, you could do this also:

```
 txtUnit.ShortcutsEnabled = False
```

Although above will also disable copying.